# find all input and select without prop disabled

Tags: jquery, validation, disabled-input

I want to select all the `input` and `select` with a class `disabled` with out the property disabled. I will use this for validation purposes.

```
var disabled3 = $('#table').find('input,select').is(':not(:disabled)').hasClass('disabled');
```

tried above but not working

```
var disabled3 = false;
console.log(disabled3);
if ($('#table').find('input,select').is(':not(:disabled)')) {
    disabled3 = $('#table').find('input,select').hasClass('disabled');
}


if (disabled3) {
    alert('Missing somefields')
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample `html` too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#table').find('input.disabled,select.disabled').not(":disabled" )
```

Also note that it will return a jquery object. Which means your if condition would be always true. Use length property to get the count of the objects and use that inside the if condition.

```
disabled3 = $('#table').find('input.disabled,select.disabled').not(":disabled" ).length;
if (length > 0) {
  alert('Missing somefields')
  return false;
}
```